Tic Tac Toe Using GUI in Java
import javax.swing.*;  //for GUI components like JFrame, JPanel, JButton
import java.awt.*; // for creating buttons and other visual components like coc=lor font etc
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class GUI{  // The main class
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private char[] num = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    private char player, computer;
    private ImageIcon playericon, computericon;
    private boolean running = true;
    public GUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic tac toe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exits the frame when click on x

        frame.setLayout(null); //used to automatically position the components in the frame but when set to null you need to set everything manually using .setBounds()

        BackgroundPanel panel = new BackgroundPanel("ticbg.jpg");//panel is used to display buttons, label( which displays te text and images)
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);  //extend the frame to full screen
        frame.setContentPane(panel);  //add all the components(buttons) to the panel.

        JButton button = new JButton();  //creates a new button
        button.setBounds(637, 500, 89, 93);
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("start button.png")); //add image to button
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());  //for border decor
        button.setFocusable(false);  //removes the box that displays around the text in the button
        button.addActionListener(e -> {  //tells what to do when click on the button
            SelectToken();
            frame.dispose(); //used to close the window/ frame and in this code moves to another frame/screen/window
        });

        panel.add(button); // adding the button to the panel
        frame.setVisible(true);// makes the frame visible


    }
    //it is called inner class
    public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {  //BackgroundPanel is a custom panel that extends JPanel to display background image
        private Image backgroundImage;

        public BackgroundPanel(String imagePath) {
            backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(imagePath).getImage();
            setLayout(null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //overriding paintComponent that draws the bg image
            super.paintComponent(g);  //clears the background to draw the image
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);  // draws the image
        }
    }


    public void SelectToken(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Select Token");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        BackgroundPanel panel2 = new BackgroundPanel("ticbg2.png");
        frame.setContentPane(panel2);
        frame.setLayout(null);


        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setBounds(650, 210, 98, 98);
        button2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("X.png"));
        button2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        button2.setFocusable(false);
        button2.addActionListener(e->{
            player = 'X';
            computer = 'O';
            playericon = new ImageIcon("X.png");
            computericon = new ImageIcon("O.png");
            button2.setEnabled(false);
        });



        JButton button3 = new JButton("O");
        button3.setBounds(650, 320, 98, 98);
        button3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("O.png"));
        button3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        button3.setFocusable(false);
        button3.addActionListener(e->{
            player = 'O';
            computer ='X';
            playericon = new ImageIcon("O.png");
            computericon = new ImageIcon("X.png");
            button3.setEnabled(false); //disabling the button once it is clicked
        });


        JButton startgame = new JButton();
        startgame.setBounds(558, 430, 280, 60);
        startgame.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Play Now.png"));
        startgame.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        startgame.setFocusable(false);
        startgame.addActionListener(e->{
            Gamegrid();
            frame.dispose();
        });


        //adding buttons to the panel2 (panel of the second frame)
        panel2.add(button2);
        panel2.add(button3);
        panel2.add(startgame);

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public void Gamegrid(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        BackgroundPanel panel3 = new BackgroundPanel("ticbg2.png");
        frame.setContentPane(panel3);

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        buttons = new JButton[9]; //creating array of buttons to form a grid
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(num[i]));
            buttons[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            buttons[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            buttons[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("gridbg.png"));
            buttons[i].setFocusable(false);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
            panel3.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    //called inner class
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener { //class to tell what to do when a button is clicked

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (running) {
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();   //e.getSource(): This part retrieves the thing that caused the action, like clicking a button.
                //(JButton): This part converts whatever e.getSource() returns into a type called JButton.
                //button: This part assigns the result of the conversion to a variable called button, so you can work with it later, like changing its text or appearance.

                int index = Integer.parseInt(button.getText()) - 1;  //first it gets what is written on the button then converts it to integer and then decreases it by 1 to match with the num array indexes
                if (num[index] == player || num[index] == computer) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid move! Please choose an empty cell.");
                } else {
                    num[index] = player;
                    button.setIcon(playericon);
                    if (checkWinner()) {
                        running = false;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
                    } else if (checkTie()) {
                        running = false;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Draw :(");
                    } else {
                        ComputerMove();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game over! Please restart to play again.");
            }

        }
    }


    public void ComputerMove() {
        // Check for a winning move
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (num[i] >= '1' && num[i] <= '9') {
                char original = num[i];
                num[i] = computer;
                if (checkWinner()) {
                    buttons[i].setIcon(computericon);
                    return; // Computer wins
                }
                num[i] = original; // Undo the move
            }
        }

        if (num[4] >= '1' && num[4] <= '9') {
            num[4] = computer;
            buttons[4].setIcon(computericon);
            return;
        }

        for (int i : new int[] { 0, 2, 6, 8 }) {
            if (num[i] >= '1' && num[i] <= '9') {
                num[i] = computer;
                buttons[i].setIcon(computericon);
                return;
            }
        }

        for (int i : new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7 }) {
            if (num[i] >= '1' && num[i] <= '9') {
                num[i] = computer;
                buttons[i].setIcon(computericon);
                return;
            }
        }

        // If no winning move, make a random move
        Random r = new Random();
        int j;
        do {
            j = r.nextInt(9);
        } while (num[j] == 'X' || num[j] == 'O');

        num[j] = computer;
        buttons[j].setIcon(computericon);
    }

    public boolean checkWinner() {
        // Check rows, columns, and diagonals
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            // Check rows
            if (num[i * 3] == num[i * 3 + 1] && num[i * 3 + 1] == num[i * 3 + 2]){
                if (num[i * 3] == player){
                    return true;
                } else if( num[i * 3] == computer){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // Check columns
            if (num[i] == num[i + 3] && num[i + 3] == num[i + 6]){
                if (num[i * 3] == player){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win :)");
                    return true;
                } else if( num[i * 3] == computer){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer Wins >_<");
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // Check diagonals
            if ((num[0] == num[4] && num[4] == num[8]) || (num[2] == num[4] && num[4] == num[6])){
                if (num[i * 3] == player){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win :)");
                    return true;
                } else if( num[i * 3] == computer){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer Wins >_<");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Check if the game is tied
    private boolean checkTie(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if (num[i] != 'X' && num[i] != 'O'){
                return false;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Draw :(");
        return true;
    }

}

I want to improve the "ComputerMove" and "CheckWinner" logic.
I made a tic_tac_toe game using GUI in java as an end of Semester Project. There are logical errors in the 'CheckWInner' and 'ComputerMove' Methods. I want to improve the logic of these methods. Your help will be appriciated. I am to submit this code the next week.
I just started using java GUI, and am confused due to the length of this code.
I reused my tic tac toe code from my previous semester (in C++).
Problem:
The main problem is that;

it displays 'Computer win' message before the computer performs it's winning move
sometimes, it does not display 'you win' message after user wins
After computer wins, it does not end game but proceeds to the user move, and displays unwanted 'you win' message
T-T


Please [edit] your question to add more details. What issues are you experiencing? How does the result your code currently produces differ from your expected result?

if this is working code, and you want it "improved", this would better be for a code review page. Try posting it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

I have stated the main problems in my code

I think the best thing for you to do is to step through the code with your debugger.  This will help you understand why the program flow is not what you expect, in the three cases you've listed above.

Your button index is wrong for the "who is the winner" check after the win condition. The if clause below // check rows it is fine but // Check columns and Check diagonals take cells into account that do not contain the win condition (num[i * 3] instead of num[i] and num[0]).
